# Why does Mars propose calling Ishimoto Mottie?

Tags: sekko-boys

In the second episode of the first season, at the beginning of the episode, when Mars calls Ishimoto "Isshie", there is the following conversation :

> Ishimoto : Isshie? Really?
>
> Mars : Would you prefer Mottie?
>
> Ishimoto : Isshie please.

[image: isshie]

I get that Isshie is the diminutive of Ishimoto, but I do not get why he would call her Mottie.

Why does Mars propose to call her Mottie and why is Ishimoto reacting that way?

Answer (score 1):

Nicknames are often derived from the beginning of names, but they can also be derived from the end as well.

So *Ishi*moto can become *Isshi*e, but Ishi*moto* can also become *mott*ie.

In English, you see this with names like Nicholas becoming Klaus.

The light novel series *Adachi and Shimamura* has several conversations/internal dialogues about nicknames, and I seem to recall "Mura" coming up at one point. But there are also points at which two characters use the later part of Adachi's name when trying to form nicknames for her, and one of them ends up calling Adachi exclusively by that last part of her name at one point.

> Addtionally, the fact that she called me "Chee-chee" the entire time suggested that she had forgotten what my name was.
>
> <sub>*Adachi and Shimamura* volume 7, page 133</sub>

And to answer the second part of your question: people get very particular about nicknames for themselves and others. In *Adachi and Shimamura*, Adachi can't bring herself to call Shimamura anything other than Shimamura. She can't even call her Hougetsu, which is Shimamura's first name.

> "Sorry, Shimamura, but I really think Shimamura fits the best."
>
> "Yeah, maybe so." And likewise--to me, she was just *Adachi*.
>
> <sub>*Adachi and Shimamura* volume 7, page 75</sub>

Additionally, Shimamura finds the nickname Shima-chan weird. And Adachi thinks it's pointless to call her Ada-chee as a nickname, because that's basically her name.

So the reason Ishimoto rejects Mottie is because she doesn't like that nickname. Given the choice between Mottie and Isshie, she chooses Isshie. Without any further introspection from her, we cannot say for certain what her actual reason is. My guess is that it's not really that deep of a reason, and she just has a gut reaction of disliking it.